# Cannot initialize Identity cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I made an ASP.NET Core website and I'm trying to set up authentication. FormsAuthentication is gone, so I guess I have to use Identity. I made a system that uses the HttpContext SignInAsync thing, but it says cookies are not initialized. I tried adding UseIdentity and AddIdentity and 10 other things to Startup.cs, but it says those are not defined. I also tried getting the Identy NuGet packages.

EDIT:
Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using StarLegacy.Web.Code.Utils;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

namespace StarLegacy.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            try
            {
                DBUtils.Init();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("startuperror.txt", exception.ToString());
                Console.Error.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddAntiforgery();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add app.UseCookieAuthentication() **before** app.UseMvc()?

Comment: That doesn't exist either :/

Comment: I would suggest to use cookie middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity, so you should add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

Comment: Thanks, that nuget package made UseCookieAuthentication exist. However, I still get this error: InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookie

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies is for creating your own middleware and that's what I am strongly recommend, it gives you more flexibility, take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

Also please provide in the question your configure and startup functions code.

P.S. app.UseCookieAuthentication() can be missed

Comment: OK, I'll try that then.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following to your .csproj:

//packages for Auth Identity

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.2" />
```

2. run cmd `dotnet restore`
3. add the using statement: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;` to `Startup.cs`
4. Add to `Startup.cs` method `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` (**You have already completed step 4 obviously**):

   ```
       app.UseCookieAuthentication();
       app.UseMvc();
   ```